# [SELECT ERROR]: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I'm using expressjs+mysql, and trying to insert values into table like below:

```
const InsertUser=(username, password, teamname, character, teamidfk, token)=>{
var Sql = "INSERT INTO `lib`.`User` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `teamname`, `character`, `teamidfk`, `token`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        let queryParams = [username,password,teamname,character,teamidfk,token];
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            connection.query(Sql,queryParams,function (err,results) {
                if(err){
                    console.log('[SELECT ERROR]:',err.message);
                } 
                resolve("success");
            });
        });
}
```

and I got error like below, how could I fix it?

```
[SELECT ERROR]: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ','eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoidXNlckQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE2MjM5M' at line 1
```

The

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoidXNlckQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE2MjM5M
```

part is JWT.
This is setting part of expressjs file:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require('express');  
var mysql = require('mysql');     
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var cors = require('cors')

const app = express();        
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors()) 
app.use(express.json());

var connection = mysql.createConnection({      
    host:'127.0.0.1',
    port:'3306',
    user:'root',
    password:'12345678',
    database:'lib'
    //multipleStatements:true
});
```

Comment: Hum, looks like your SQL driver is passing a text parameter without escaping it. Sounds strange.

Comment: so how to fix it?

Comment: it was before the token

Comment: I'm not sure about this but `lib.user` and `id` those part without parameter passing should be quote with `'` ? at least in sql syntax itself a database object be quote with `'` will cause problem.

Comment: @T.Peter After I edited it follow your advice like```var Sql = "INSERT INTO 'lib'.'User' ('id', `username`, `password`, `teamname`, `character`, `teamidfk`, `token`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)```, the error becomes ```...the right syntax to use near ''lib'.'User' ('id', `username`, `password`, `teamname`, `character`, `teamidfk`,' at line 1```

Comment: @AmantuerRewuhan oh I'm sorry those are typo, what I mean is maybe not quote `lib.user` and `id` at all? or quote with proper database object indicator `"` or `[]`.

Comment: @fadlikidd which part exactlly?

Comment: @T.Peter I edited to ```var Sql = "INSERT INTO lib.User (id, `username`, `password`, `teamname`, `character`, `teamidfk`, `token`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; ``` and the error become to ```...syntax to use near ', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoidXNlckUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE2NDA5' at line 1```  more one space at the left of ```'eyJhb...```than the orginal one.

Comment: Based on the error message, the problematic value is coming right before the token = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoidXNlckQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE2MjM5M`.. maybe the translated value looks something like `'somevalue' ','eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoidXNlckQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE2MjM5M'` etc.. maybe the value before that is already being closed with a single quote OR the value contains backslash.. can you get all the values that need to be inserted?

Comment: @fadlikidd thanks I fixed by your advice. There is mistake with the value of `teamidfk`